# Value of derivative of a function and a derivative

Tags: calculus, derivatives

If $x'(t)<0$ for $t<1$

and

$x'(t)>0$ for $t>1,$

how do we conclude that $x(t)$\geq$x(1)=0?$

Comment: This is false: let $x(t) = \frac{1}{2}t^2-t$.

Comment: Added information is required.

Comment: Given x(t) is x(t) =(1/q)+(t/p)-t^(1/p). I mistook the text in the book to mean it was valid for all functions. However, I am unable to figure it out for the given function as well

Answer (score 0):

From these conditions alone, it does not follow that $x(1)=0$.

However, $x'(t)>0$ for $t>1$ implies that $x$ is increasing on $[1,\infty)$. Similarly, $x'(t)<0$ for $t<1$ implies $x$ is decreasing on $(-\infty,1]$. Hence, $x(t)\geq x(1)$ for all $t$.

EDIT: We can prove this quite easily using the Mean Value Theorem. We will prove that

> **Claim:** If $f:(a,b)\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is differentiable and $f'>0$, then $f$ is strictly increasing.

but the analagous proposition can be proved similarly.

*Proof:* Suppose there were $x,y\in(a,b)$ with $x<y$ but $f(x)\geq f(y)$. Then by the Mean Value Theorem there would be some $c\in(x,y)$ with

$$f'(c)=\frac{f(y)-f(x)}{y-x}\leq 0,$$

contradicting the positivity of $f'$. It follows that no such pair $(x,y)$ exists. $\square$